# Tensorflow Docker container on Windows: how to install python package

Tags: docker, tensorflow, python-packaging

I have a Docker on my Windows machine and tensorflow image. I can run jupyter notebook but do not know how to install additional python packages into my docker container

Answer (score 1):

After some inverstigation I found a solution. To run docker container use the command:

```
$ docker run -it -p 8888:8888 gcr.io/tensorflow/tensorflow bash
```

Bash will allow to run some commands in the container. So, you can use `pip` to install python packages:

```
pip install Pillow
```

If you need to update pip, run:

```
python -m pip install -U pip
```

The last step is to run jupyter notebook:

```
jupyter notebook
```